# Visual studio .net core 2 opens new browser window while debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

How can I prevent visual studio 2017 to open a new window when I tried to debug asp.net core application?

Previously it's used to open just a tab in web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Options > Dedugging > General > uncheck the option Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).

https://www.johanbostrom.se/blog/how-to-disable-the-built-in-chrome-from-starting-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

It's a VS setting in your project properties. Open them and go to the Web tab and select "don't open page, wait for a request from an external app".